# When will my highest-voted comments appear in my profile?

Tags: support, comments, profile-page, comment-voting

Now this is a blast from the past. See what I found in a [blog post from April 2009](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/comments-now-with-flags-and-votes/) (the introduction to comment voting):

> your best comments will also show up in your user profile page, but this isn’t implemented yet.

So, just another 6 to 8 weeks then, right?

Comment: +1, but I'm not sure I really want to be reminded of how far away I am from the Pundit badge

Comment: +1 best new tag ever.

Comment: @Ether: I actually tried [promises-coming-back-to-haunt-you] first, but it was truncated.

Comment: Where's that question with the list of people's favorite comments?

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

Comment: Pretty verbose answer there. Might want to trim it a bit.

Comment: -1; I can't read wall-of-text answers. Please add a tl;dr summary

Answer (score 1):

+1 for this.  Until then, you can get a monthly update on your comment scores with the Stack Exchange data explorer query:

http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/99/my-comment-score-distribution