# Comments missing from data dump

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, data-dump

When checking on a [discussion over approaching punditry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43204/when-will-my-highest-voted-comments-appear-in-my-profile/43206#43206), I noticed that the data dump (at least the one for Meta) seems to be missing quite a few comments. The most recent data dump includes 33256 comments. Considering that we're approaching comment ID 100000 on meta, I doubt that the whole rest was deleted. I didn't run around hunting for lots of examples, but comment [80017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36888/spell-fix-in-user-profile-1-questions/#comment-80017) is one, at least.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there were a lot of deleted comments, but 70% is a little high.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42601/should-we-have-a-policy-about-too-much-downvoting/42611#42611 Not too sure what happened there.

Comment: @Jon Seigel: Those long discussion threads sometimes get erased; that's normal. What I'm talking about are comments that are *not* deleted on the site, but are missing from the data dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These missing comments will be in the next data dump.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/creative-commons-data-dump-mar-10/#comment-44831

Comment: Thanks, Geoff. Looks like Greg was faster than me on that catch.