# Can I see how many votes my comments have?

Tags: support, comments, comment-voting

I recently won a '[Pundit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/40/pundit)' badge for having 10 comments with a score of +5 or more. I then proceeded to waste more time than I'm comfortable admitting to trying to find which comments were well liked enough to bolster my ego.

There is no way that I can see to sort comments by number of upvotes on the profile page. Is there any way to do this? I know there is an API somewhere, but I don't know how to use it yet.

I found ["When will my highest-voted comments appear in my profile?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43204/when-will-my-highest-voted-comments-appear-in-my-profile), but it doesn't seem to have made it into the shiny new profile revamp either.

Comment: SEDE is *teh answerz* to all things.

Comment: Also: [Can I view a list of my “great comments”, perhaps in my profile?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130906/262755)

Comment: Thanks everyone! Much better links provided all around.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296061/229836

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can wait till sunday, because that is when [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) gets updated, you can run this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/367030?UserId=1146608)

```sql
select id as [Comment Link]
, postid as [Post Link]
, score
from comments
where userid = ##userid##
order by score desc
```

Notice the two [Magic Link columns](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#magic-columns) I used, `[Comment Link]` and `[Post Link]`, to have SEDE generate links to the comment and your post.

Answer (score 1):

I found the My Comment Score distribution query and came up with [this basic extension](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/revision/367028/473029/my-comments-by-score) (that I'm sure someone has done before me).

```
DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

SELECT 
    Id,
    PostId,
    Text,
    Score
FROM 
    Comments
WHERE 
    UserId = @UserId
ORDER BY 
    Score DESC
```

If someone can suggest an improvement, there are two things I would like to add:

- Post title – can't figure out how to join
- Link to comment – can't figure out how to link to a comment by comment ID only – it appears to need the post Id and/or title url. I also haven't found whether or not there's support for text operations.